# Validate attachments for file size?

Tags: plugin-sproutforms

Does anyone know if it's possible to validate the size of an attachment for Sprout Forms file upload? I'd like to limit attachments to a maximum file size.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if that's possible since I never used Sproud Forms but you can easily create a custom field type with the additional validation rule.

1. Create a [Plugin](https://craftcms.com/docs/plugins/introduction) you can use [Pluginfactory.io](https://pluginfactory.io/) for that and install it
2. Create a new [Field](https://craftcms.com/docs/plugins/field-types)
3. Just extend the basic `AssetsFieldType`

   ```
   class myNewAssetField extends AssetsFieldType{

   }
   ```
4. Take a look at the default validation rules for [BaseElementFieldType](https://craftcms.com/classreference/fieldtypes/BaseElementFieldType)

   ```
   public function validate($value)
   {
       $errors = array();

       if ($this->allowLimit && ($limit = $this->getSettings()->limit) && is_array($value) && count($value) > $limit)
       {
           if ($limit == 1)
           {
               $errors[] = Craft::t('There can’t be more than one selection.');
           }
           else
           {
               $errors[] = Craft::t('There can’t be more than {limit} selections.', array('limit' => $limit));
           }
       }

       if ($errors)
       {
           return $errors;
       }
       else
       {
           return true;
       }
   }
   ```
5. Copy the function above in your new class and include something like this somewhere

   ```
   foreach ($value as $assetId){
       $asset = craft()->assets->getFileById($assetId);
       if($asset->size >= 10){ // insert your size here
           $errors[] = Craft::t('Your file is too large');
       }
   }
   ```

It took me about 5 minutes to create this new field type to allow the validation of file sizes

If you want to make it look pretty and create a setting to dynamically set the individual max file size for each field you can include the function [getSettingsHtml](https://github.com/pixelandtonic/Craft-Release/blob/master/app/fieldtypes/BaseElementFieldType.php#L101) in your new class and change add your new value (for example maxSize) you can then grab the new size with `$this->getSettings()->maxSize`